# Meaning of phrase "apart altogether"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, legalese

I was reading a book and came across the following sentence:

> The question of the value of the chattels on the land in the present
>   case might, as my brother Windeyer point out, arise and have to be
>   decided in a variety of circumstance **apart altogether** from the deed of
>   15 July 1995.

I never heard this phrase before and wondered what it meant.

Comment: "in a variety fo circumstance **totally different** from the deed of.."

Comment: Or "a variety of circumstance **separate** from the deed of..."

Comment: A classic example of an _oxymoron_ where **apart** and **altogether** contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means *'completely apart'* or *'completely unrelated'*. 
In this context, there was a deed that has been dated 15 July 1995 that already talks about a set of *'circumstance'*. To answer the present question, a decision must be taken based on a new set of *'circumstance'*  that is completely unrelated to the one specified in the deed mentioned earlier.

PS, I am not sure what the book is about, I've tried to explain the context based on what I got from the extract.